# Bootstrap 3.1.1 navbar wont collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using the following markup to create a collapsable navbar, but it isn't working.

When the screen size narrows the navbar items simply disappear rather than collapse into a lined button.

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">Logout</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">New Post</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

My JS Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/meconlin/gspDY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you need a toggle button..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Logout</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="./">New Post</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

http://bootply.com/131875